# unable to scroll gridview embeded in nestedscrollview

Tags: android, gridview

my gridview does not scroll.  i have 10 items in the gridview but only 6 show and some of the items at the bottom at cut off.

Here is the layout of the gridview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/expanded_toolbar_title_margin_start"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/yelp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/nestedscrollview"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridContainerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >


        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/grid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:columnWidth="100dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:listSelector="#00000000"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

and here are two photos of the issue.  when i scroll upwards it pushes the yelp image up but it wont do the nested scrolling on the gridview, why ?

[image]

[image]

UPDATE:
i also tried doing this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mGridView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
        }
```

AND IT STARTED WORKING ON API lollipop. But i need it to run on older devices also. why wont it scroll on devices before lollipop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use RecyclerView with GridLayout instead of GridView. Then disabling nested scrolling, can be done on pre lollipop version.

Answer (score 1):

`GridView` has its own inbuilt scrolling behaviour. So why would you use `NestedScrollView`? Click the link below to see `GridViews'` documentation..

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

That is why `GridView` is conflicting with it.